# Dell Latitude D830 DVD Drive Not Recognized

Tags: dvd

Unlike some people who have issues with the video or WiFi drivers, I suffer from not being able to use the DVD drive on this laptop. Upon POST, the BIOS sees it and I am able to open the tray as well; however, once the system starts to load up Ubuntu or other distros (Debian and Linux Mint), I lose all functionality. Plus, I don't see it listed as a device in the OS. I've poured over the internet the past few days trying to see if anyone else has the issue, or did and found a solution but sadly, nothing anywhere so far. So, I thought I would ask the community here and see what you all think. Worse case scenario, I have some dead weight to a nice little machine. Thanks!

PS I honestly think Linux doesn't like the IDE interface the disc drive has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is apparently a known problem from long ago.  The author of [this article](http://www.linlap.com/dell_latitude_d830) suggests that you best bet is to get an external USB drive. There was some support at [Dell](http://downloads.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/latitude-d830.html) for a version of RedHat, but these are so old they will be useless.

Comment: The thing linked on the Dell website is a firmware updater, not a driver. Did you try updating to the latest of your DVD drives firmware?

Comment: I'll give the firmware a go. I'll report back on if it worked or not. Thanks for the quick replies , much appreciated.

Comment: @alexander255 The firmware update worked like a charm, thanks for the suggestion. For everyone else, I had the TSST-TS-L632H-SLIM-8X-DVD drive and I used this firmware for it: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R250068&fileId=2731128725&osCode=WLH&productCode=latitude-d830&languageCode=EN&categoryId=RS and used the DOS based updater on a bootable DOS USB stick. Took 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so the suggestion alexander255 gave worked. I had the TSST-TS-L632H-SLIM-8X-DVD drive on my D830 which I have the firmware update linked here:

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R250068&fileId=2731128725&osCode=WLH&productCode=latitude-d830&languageCode=EN&categoryId=RS

I used the DOS based updater with my bootable DOS USB drive and it was quick and painless. Thanks again for the help, now I have an old Dell D830 working at 100% on Linux. Off to work on the D810 I just got...