# DVDs won't play on Dell Latitude D830 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, dvd

I just recently got a Dell Latitude D830 and loaded Ubuntu 14.04 on it and DVDs are not recognized, but CDs play normally. The Dell D830 uses the same CD/DVD drive as the Dell D620 so this is puzzling to me. I'm looking for assistance on how to get the proper drivers for the CD/DVD drive to run on my D830 with Ubuntu 14.04 as my OS. I need someone to walk me through the steps as I am still newbie. Thanks.

Jim Mc

Comment: By DVD you mean commercial movies DVDs?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem [two years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481120/dell-latitude-d830-dvd-drive-not-recognized) apparently the Dell d830 dvd drive doesn't play nicely with Ubuntu and in the thread they recommend purchasing an external DVD drive. You might have to bite the bullet and buy a new machine. I notice yours only comes with 60, 80, 100, 120 or 160GB hard disk drives and 512MB to 4 GB RAM with a Intel Core 2 Duo processor. It's only worth a hundred bucks. If you want an external DVD player (hooked up to one of your 3 USB ports) you can find one for [$17.80](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-3-0-LightScribe-DVD-ROM-CD-RW-DVD-RW-Burner-External-Drive-for-PC-Laptop-/262526556581?hash=item3d1fcd59a5:g:GMoAAOSww9VXh1B~)

Comment: The same question you quote shows the user found a solution installing the latest firmware via dos.